# Twilio IP Messaging : one sec latency before sent messages be displayed

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am discovering the Twilio IP messaging sdk that i plan to integrate in my project.. I am using the Twilio [IP Messaging SDK For Javascript](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/sdks#javascript-sdk) .

So i am testing it via the getting started code and everithing works fine.

However , i am facing a little issue that disturb me a little bit. When i am sending a message, it happens a little bit of time before the message get displayed in the chat window. About 1 sec.

I know it's not a huge latency but my goal is to build the most reactive chat possible. I think the problem come from the Twilio's sendMessage() function. I don't know how to fix it. if you don't see what i mean, take for example the Facebook chat. When you typing something and you press enter, you will see immediately what you entered displayed in the chat window, isn't it ? But with Twilio, there is a little latency time (about 1 sec), before the message showing up.

It's a real problem, so what should i do to make the sendMessage() function more reactive ?

Sincerely,

Comment: If you mean that the message takes 1 second to be shown on the sender's "chatbox", then maybe you are showing the message only after a network-bound event happens.

Comment: You could manually print the message to the chat window right after your do `.sendMessage()`. Next, when you your channel receives a "messageAdded" event, you can now update your printed message as required.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel didn't set any event to be processed before showing the message in the chatbox. It is really a matter with the twilio's sendMessage function. Even the console.log (to test the messageAdded event) message take the same amount of time to be displayed, so nothing to do with the printMessage function.

Comment: @Johndoe Additionally the 1sec latency you are receiving is due to the Twilio API calls and the event firing system.

Comment: @Quirk OMG i am so stupid. Thanks quirk. All i was needed to do was print the content outside the sendMessage().  Finally very simple. Thank you again

Comment: @Johndoe Well unless you are looking for more specific answers on the inner workings of your stack, you should probably close the question. Perhaps write an answer to your problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Special thanks to Quirk.

All i was needed to do was print the content outside the sendMessage(). Finally very simple.